# The prefix "context" for element "context:annotation-config" is not bound

Tags: spring

I am trying to use  to make my Spring application work with annotations. But I am getting an error: that the prefix "context" for element "context:annotation-config" is not found.

Can anyone tell what the root cause for this is.

Answer (score 5):

You are missing the required xml name space entries

Spring reference [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/core.html#beans-annotation-config)

make sure you context.xml is similar to the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context
        https://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <context:annotation-config/>

</beans>
```